# Python - Validation checks on an input

Tags: python

Currently I am writing some validation code for an input in my program and I cannot seem to get the error message to display correctly!

I have my types defined in a string list like this:

```
types = ['Guitar','Piano','Drums','Violin','Voice','Flute','Cello','Bass']
```

Then my code for the validation check is:

```
    typevalid = False
    while typevalid == False:
      Type =  input("Please enter the tutor type: ").title()
      for count in range (0,7):
        if Type == types[count]:
          typevalid = True
          Tutor = (Name,Type)       
          insert_data(Tutor)
          print("New data added")
          print()
        if Type != types[count]:
          print("!!Please enter a correct type!!\n")
    add = input("Do you wish to add another record? (y/n) ")
```

I have tried changing and moving the second if Type code and it either repeats the error X amount of times becuase of the range loop or it will display the error message twice.

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: @thefourtheye Well my error message is either display 7 times into the code as an error or displaying twice once in the loop and once outside the loop. I am trying to find the error in my code to stop this happening and if there is an easier way of coding the validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions:

```
types = ["guitar", "piano", ...] # note case

while True:
    type_ = str(input("Please enter the tutor type: "))
    if type_.lower() in types: # checks all items in types in one line
        break # leave while loop
    print("Please enter a correct type!") # only happens once per loop
```

You can add your other functionality around this core logic. If you want the leading capital letters back later, you can use `type_.capitalize()`.

Comment: Thank you that has helped a lot! Using both yours and Luke's code I have gotten in to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a couple of problems - `types` has 8 elements but your `for` loop goes over `range(0,7)`. Better to rewrite as `for count in range(len(types)):`

More significantly, your second `if` statement doesn't work - it checks one `Type` each time (either in the loop or out of the loop). What you need to do is check that none have been found. Try this:

```
typevalid = False
while typevalid == False:
    Type =  input("Please enter the tutor type: ").title()
    for count in range(len(types)):
        if Type == types[count]:
            typevalid = True
            Tutor = (Name,Type)       
            insert_data(Tutor)
            print("New data added")
            print()

    if typevalid == False:
      print("!!Please enter a correct type!!\n")
add = input("Do you wish to add another record? (y/n) ")
```

NB: Just seen jonrsharpe's response - it's much cleaner but this may explain what's going wrong in your current code.

Comment: Yes that did explain what was going wrong and now I am kicking myself as I completely forgot to use len! Using both yours and jonrsharpe's code I have gotten in to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You never break out of the loop:

```
for count in range(0,7):
    if Type == types[count]:
        # need to add the following lines:
        typevalid == True
        break
```

A few additional suggestions:

- Rather than looping over `types` manually, use the builtin membership checking functionality
  of `in`

  - Do `if Type in types:` instead of `for count in range(...`
  - Better yet, since you are checking `types` over and over again, it's much more efficient to use a `set`: `set(['Guitar', 'Piano', ...])`, or (in Python 2.7+) simply `{'Guitar', 'Piano', ... }`.
- Uppercase variables are conventionally used for class names in python. You should use lower case names instead. If you want to avoid overriding the builtin `type` variable, use a trailing underscore (`type_`), or simply make your variable more descriptive (e.g. `tutor_type`)

After these suggestions, your code would look something like this:

```
tutor_types = {'guitar', 'piano', 'drums', 'violin', 'voice', 'flute', 'cello', 'bass'}
while True:
    tutor_type = input('Please enter the tutor type: ').lower()
    if tutor_type in tutor_types:
        # Valid input logic here
        break # don't forget to break out of the loop

    print('The error message the user receives after entering incorrect info!')
```